# How to append the content from a list from one function to another

Tags: python, function, networkx

I will show you my code then I'll explain what I'm trying to do

```py
import networkx as nx

def primeFactors(n): 
    primelist=[]
    while n % 2 == 0: 
        primelist.append(2) 
        n = n / 2
        
    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n))+1,2): 

        while n % i== 0: 
            primelist.append(i) 
            n = n / i 
    if n > 2: 
        primelist.append(n) 
    print(primelist)

def iterate(num):
    numlist=[]
    for n in range(num):
        if(n >= 2):
            p = primeFactors(n)
            numlist.append(p)
            print(numlist)
            prime=TrialDivision(n)
            if(prime):
                #G.add_node(n)
                G.add_nodes_from(numlist)
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold',node_color='green')
```

Basically, I'm trying to plot the prime factors of a number, let's say from 2 to 20, and plot them. The first function is taking all the prime factors and puts them in the primelist list. And what I want from the iterate function is to plot all the prime factors of ALL the numbers I iterate through. But the problem is if I use `G.add_node(n)` it just shows the prime numbers from 2-20 not the prime factors of all the numbers in that range. and when I try to use `G.add_nodes_from(numlist)` it just prints `[None, None, None, None, None]`. If I iterate through 10 numbers the output is this:

```
[2]
[3]
[2, 2]
[5]
[2, 3.0]
[7]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 3]
[2, 5.0]
[11]
[2, 2, 3.0]
[13]
[2, 7.0]
```

Can I take all those lists from the first function put them in one list and print them in the second function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're getting `None` because your `primeFactors` function returns the result of the print function which is `None` (the function prints the right value to the console, but the returned value from the function is None). Switch that to `return(primelist)` in order to actually set the resulting value to your variablein the `iterate function`.

Second, once you return the correct value, you should get an error from your `G.add_nodes_from(numlist)` call because numlist will be a list of lists. Instead of `numlist.append(p)` you should use `numlist.extend(p)`. The first one adds the list `p` as another element in the `numlist` list, while the second one takes each element in `p` and adds them as lists.

I didn't have your `TrialDivision` function so I couldn't fully test this modifications through your whole code, so you may have to retest with that piece.